# Change vertical header title

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

How I can change title shown on the picture to "№". Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want a vertical header ? You could also add a column "№" to your table instead.

Comment: Yeah, but, when I remove the rows 2,5 from 1,2,3,4,5? № 1,3,4 stays without sorting? I'm tryed this. But, I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That widget is an object of the `QTableCornerButton` class that inherits from `QAbstractButton` but it is a class that is part of the private Qt API that does not use text, so you can not use `setText()` of `QAbstractButton`, so the other option is establish a `QLabel` with a layout above:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableView w;
    QStandardItemModel model(10, 10);
    w.setModel(&model);
    QAbstractButton *button =  w.findChild<QAbstractButton *>();
    if(button){
        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(button);
        lay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        QLabel *label = new QLabel("№");
        label->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        lay->addWidget(label);
    }
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: @sherox Qt Designer is limited, but the same logic you have to do in the .cpp, 
 change `w.findChild<QAbstractButton *>()` by `ui->tableView->findChild<QAbstractButton *>()`

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm using Qt Designer. I have QSqlQueryModel and tableView. I'm using this code "model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Title"));" for it. I want to change vertical header titleas shown above. Just change text.

Comment: @sherox As you point out, what you marked in a red rectangle is not handled by the model, assuming that your QTableView is `ui->tableView` only adds the following to the constructor of the class generated by Qt Designer:: `QAbstractButton *button =  ui->tableView->findChild<QAbstractButton *>();
    if(button){
        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(button);
        lay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        QLabel *label = new QLabel("№");
        label->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        lay->addWidget(label);
    }`

Comment: It's WORKS, Thank you Sir.